# Jquery Accordion/CSS Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

All I want is, at the example [which can be found here](http://sixtydegreedays.com/test/), is the grey box which appears when you click on the 'how to' box to remain ABOVE the elements below. I have been trying to play with z-index but it doesn't seem to work.

I don't really want it to push the other elements out of position when opened, which happens if I remove the height attribute from the parent li, just to expand out as it does, but above everything else.

Must be a z-index solution but I couldn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the `acitem` class which should do the trick

Comment: Thats done the trick! Thanks ScampDoodle. SO won't let me mark this answered for another 5 minutes but i'll mark it then :)